# How do you echo sql query into radio button? php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, list, radio-button

When I run this code, it only generates one radio button with one petname, the value doesn't work. I want it to generate all the petnames in the database and for the value associated with petId.

```
 <form id="petshop"  action="pet.php"  method="get">

 <p>choose PetName:

 <?php  

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){

 $petid= $row["petID"];
 $petname = $row["petName"];
 }
 ?>

  <input type="radio" value="<?php echo$petid; ?>" name='petName'><?php echo      $petname; ?> />

<p><input type="submit" value="submit"/>
```

Where did I go wrong? Please help, I am new to php and mysql.

Comment: Your `<input>` is outside the loop.... Also you have a stray `/>`.

Comment: Moreover what is the value of `$rs` ??

Answer (score 1):

you please try this.the problem is your while loop

```
 <p>choose PetName:

<?php  

 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){

 $petid= $row["petID"];
 $petname = $row["petName"];

 ?>

  <input type="radio" value="<?php echo $petid; ?>" name='petName'><?php echo $petname; ?> 
 <?php  } ?>

   <p><input type="submit" value="submit"/>
```

Comment: worked for generating the petnames but the value is not working.

Comment: which value you mean?

Comment: value ="<?php echo $petid; ?>".

Comment: try the 2nd answer it must work

Comment: When I select a petname and click submit, i want it to use the petId to generate an info table.

Comment: you must check $petid has value.it works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php  

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){

 $petid= $row["petID"];
 $petname = $row["petName"];
?>
 <input type="radio" value="<?php echo $petid; ?>" name='petName'><?php echo $petname; ?> />
<?php
 }
 ?>
```

This should do the trick.

Also: Where is your query?

Comment: I didnt include query here but I do have it.

Comment: did this code work for you? edit: Also: starting programming allways brings "stupid" mistakes like this one (i know that by myself)...a little praxis and doing this like 10 times and you just know how to do it.

Comment: Its the same as azhar code and yes it did for generating the petnames.. but the value which needs to be the petId isnt working.

Answer (score -1):

You have to put Radio box inside the loop

```
<?php  
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){
echo "<input type='radio' value='$petid' name='petName' />";
echo $petname;
}  ?>
```

Comment: <ou opened php tags in an echo...this aint gonna work.